# ActiveRecord query: where a field is not true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I want to find all records where a field is not true. The working AR syntax for this is:

```
Dog.where(:stray => [false, nil])
```

Is there a less verbose way of querying for 'not true'? It really sucks having to cater for this mysql nuance everywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's Arel, you are just using AR (which in turn will use Arel or whatever).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can write `Dog.where(Dog.arel_table[:stray].not_eq(true))`.

As a side note, I'd recommend that you set a default value for the `stray` column in the database, or at least require a value for it. That way you wouldn't have to make this workaround.

Comment: While the syntax is particularly pretty, what I absolutely agree with is that the database should have default value. This cleanly avoids any lengthy syntax. Thanks!

Comment: This generates the following SQL for me (via to_sql):

`SELECT "dogs".* FROM "dogs"  WHERE ("dogs"."stray" != 't')`

Which is not the same as `WHERE stray = false OR stray IS NULL`

Answer (score 7):

How about a named scope?

`scope :not_stray, where("stray IS NULL OR stray = false")`

Then use:

`Dog.not_stray`

Comment: This is the idiomatic way to handle it, but I would also recommend the default value that @Frost mentioned.

Comment: Sure. I prefer to keep that sort of thing in the business logic layer rather than the database. So he could add a validation that a true or false value is present for the stray attribute.